# Values of $t \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f^{-1}(t)$ is an embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2-yz$. For what values of $t \in \mathbb{R}$, is $f^{-1}(t)$ an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R^3}$ of dimension $2$?

The Jacobian of this function is of the form $[2x-2,-z,-y]$. The jacobian has full rank unless $x=1,y=0$ and $z=0$. Also $f(1,0,0)=0$. Thus I have to look at $f^{-1}(t)$ for $t=0$. Now the hessian matrix at $t=0$ is of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $D_1=2, D_2=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},D_3=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Then $|D_1|=2, |D_2|=0,|D_3| \ne 0$. Hence $(1,0,0)$ is a saddle point. Thus $f^{-1}(t)$ is an embedded submanifold except for when $t=0$.

Is this alright?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What does the saddle point nature of $(1,0,0)$ if you *graph* $f$ have to do with the question at hand? You haven't decided whether the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ in $\Bbb R^3$ is an embedded surface or not. What shape is it?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure if I understand your question. But every regular level set  of a smooth map between smooth manifolds is an embedded submanifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Saddle point would mean that the curve is self intersecting. Is not it?

Comment: You've decided, correctly, that $f^{-1}(t)$ is embedded for every $t\ne 0$. You have *not* shown that $f^{-1}(0)$ fails to be. Actually, you haven't actually demonstrated that you have a saddle point, but are you then claiming that if you slice with the tangent plane at a saddle point, you get a singularity? Why not just examine the surface $f=0$ directly in $\Bbb R^3$ and decide what is going on?

Comment: I thought that I showed that $(1,0,0)$ is a saddle point by looking at the Hessian Matrix

Comment: @TedShifrin How do you I examine the surface directly in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You could try actually drawing it. What is the shape? How do you decide whether it is or is not an embedded submanifold?

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought that $(1,0,0) \in f^{-1}(0)$ and $(1,0,0)$ is a saddle point. So it can't be a regular point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it might be difficult to tell if a set is an embedded smooth submanifold or not. However, in your case, you are lucky because $f^{-1}(0)$ is not even a two-dimensional topological manifold near $(1,0,0)$.

Note that your function $f$ is a translated quadratic form (it is of the form $x'^2 = yz$ for $x' = x - 1$). This form has signature $(+,+,-)$ so the zero level set $S = f^{-1}(0)$ is an [elliptic double cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone) (plot done using wolfram cloud):

[image]

Intuitively, this is not a topological two-dimensional manifold near the vertex $v = (1,0,0)$. To see this formally, note that any open neighborhood $U$ of $v$ in $S$ has the property that $U \setminus \{ v \}$ is disconnected (by throwing away $v$ we split the cone into two parts). Hence, $U$ cannot be homeomorphic to a two-dimensional open ball because if you throw away a point from a two-dimensional open ball, you are left with a connected space.

Comment: Is there an way to do it without plotting the graph?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: You can prove the last part formally without drawing a picture by writing $S = S_{+} \cup S_{-} \cup \{v\}$ where $S_{+} = S \cup \{ z > 0\}$ and $S_{-} = S \cup \{ z < 0 \}$ and showing that $S_{\pm}$ are both open and closed in $S \setminus \{ v \}$.